# select month and year seperatly

Tags: flutter, flutter-date-range-picker

I want to make the month picker and the year picker separate. For example,there are two datepicker icons in the UI. If the user taps on the first icon, it should display the month picker (it should show only the month of the currently selected year); if they tap on the second icon, it should display the year picker (it should show only the years). How can I achieve this?

tried the syncfusion_flutter_datepicker. but it seems harder to customize. if you guys have experience with'syncfusion_flutter_datepicker'. Please let me know how to achieve this or suggest any other methods.